# How do I use the Insert key in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I'm working on a project that shows a menu in a game. But to open up the menu you have to press the Insert key. I found 2 ways to do that but they both give me errors. Here's the code:

```
      Dim insert As Boolean = GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.Insert)
```

or

```
     GetAsyncKeyState(118)
```

The error I'm getting is `PInvoke restriction: cannot return variants`

I'm not very familiar with this stuff so please help, How do I make it so I can press the insert key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is WinForms, set the form's KeyPreview to true and override the OnKeyDown method:

```
Public Class Form1

  Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    Me.KeyPreview = True
  End Sub

  Protected Overrides Sub OnKeyDown(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs)
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Insert Then
      MessageBox.Show("I'm inserting!")
    End If
  End Sub

End Class
```